# DOM attribute access: why is "elt.class" not working?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have this javascript code:

```
var elt = document.createElement("div");
elt.class = "class_1";
```

There is supposed to be a styling associated with `.class_1` in my CSS, but it did not really apply for some reason. After spent a few hours figuring out what went wrong, I tried this alternative:

```
elt.setAttribute("class", "class_1");
```

and it worked....

It is weird since on the other part of my code, I used `elt.id` and it worked just fine. At first I thought it was a cross-browser issue, but it turned out that `"elt.class"` doesnt work in all browser.

Is this a bug in the native javascript DOM? can somebody explain why this is or if I did anything wrong? Thanks. All inputs/answers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Properties and attributes are different things. Attributes are the strings you see in the document code, accessible for any type of document through the [DOM Core method `getAttribute`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-666EE0F9):

```
<a id="foo" href="bar" tabindex="1" onclick="alert()" class="bof" potato="lemon">

a.getAttribute('id')         // string "foo"
a.getAttribute('href')       // string "bar"
a.getAttribute('tabindex')   // string "1"
a.getAttribute('onclick')    // string "alert()"
a.getAttribute('class')      // string "bof"
a.getAttribute('potato')     // string "lemon"
```

whereas the properties, accessible directly on the object, are specialised and document-type-specific (eg defined in [DOM HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/) or [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/)) and are generally more readable convenience facilities. Although they often reflect the same thing as the attribute, they can differ in terms of name, value, type or purpose.

```
a.id                         // string "foo"
a.href                       // string "http://www.example.com/base/bar"
a.tabIndex                   // integer 1
a.onclick                    // function() { alert(); }
a.className                  // string "bof"
a.potato                     // undefined
```

So whilst `id` results in the same value, `href` and all other URL properties get absolutised relative to the document; `tabIndex` and other numeric properties returns a Number instead of literal string; `onclick` and other event handler properties return a JS Function object, and properties whose name happens to clash with common reserved words like `class` (not just only JavaScript reserved words, as DOM is a cross-language standard) get renamed (see also: `htmlFor`), and non-standard attributes aren't accessible as properties at all. Other gotchas: `value`/`selected`/`checked` on inputs reflect the *current* contents of a form field; the attributes of the same name are the `defaultValue`/`defaultSelected`/`defaultChecked` initial values.

[Aside: IE<8 has real trouble telling the difference between attributes and properties, and will return the wrong thing for `getAttribute` in all cases where they differ. Don't let this confuse you, and avoid using `getAttribute` for accessing HTML DOM properties for this reason.]

Answer (score 4):

"class" is a reserved word in JavaScript, so the DOM uses `className` to reflect the element's current class(es). This is represented in string form. Ex: `"foo bar baz"` (an element with classes `foo`, `bar`, and`baz`)

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.className for examples of how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

```
var elt = document.createElement("div");
elt.className = "class_1";
```

Answer (score 1):

Class is a reserved word. To access the class attribute use className. `elt.className = "class_1";`