# get element by id and then class attribute

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to get an elements class name. First I find the element by its id and then I tried to get the class attribute doing the following. My results return undefined. How can I get the text from the class attribute? Which would be "not-checked-in".

html

```
<div id="last-check-in" class="not-checked-in"></div>
```

javascript

```
var checkedin;
checkedin = document.getElementById("last-check-in");
console.log(checkedin.class);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [DOM attribute access: why is "elt.class" not working?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6670756/dom-attribute-access-why-is-elt-class-not-working)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of simply `class`, use `className`:

```
var checkedin = document.getElementById("last-check-in");
console.log(checkedin.className);
```

Comment: The SO pattern "ugly *but correct* answer first, then beautifying after" in action ;-)

Comment: @zerkms - isn't that better than the "nicely formatted *but incorrect* answer first, then correcting after" pattern ;-)

Comment: @Joseph Silber: it is :-) Actually I do the same, wasn't fast enough this time :-)

Answer (score 1):

You may use: `getAttribute("class")`

```
var checkedin;
checkedin = document.getElementById("last-check-in");
console.log(checkedin.getAttribute("class"));
```

### [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/UjWqC/)